# How to get admin order items from admin order quote

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to get the items which are present in quote of admin order.

```
\Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $adminQuote
\Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $adminCreate
```

to get the details but whenever i call call getItems, getAllvisibleItems, getAllItems its returning null value.

I need to get the item details which are under quote when you are placing an order from admin.
Can any one let me know how to do that.

Comment: Could you paste your code here? This is only going to work if the action is executed by the same admin user. At the `\Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote` session, you would be able to get the quote calling the method `getQuote`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the **\Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote** to get the item details which are under quote when you are placing an order from admin.

```
    use \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote;

    public function __construct( 
            ... 
            \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $backendQuoteSession 
            ... 
        ) { 
            ... 
            $this->backendQuoteSession = $backendQuoteSession; 
            ... 

        }

    public function yourFunction() { 
       $items = $this->backendQuoteSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

        foreach ($items as $item) { 
        { 
            echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
            echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
            echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
            echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
            echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
            echo "<br />";   
        }
    }
```

Comment: this I need to apply based on condition how to know that order is creating from admin?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create . I have used this class to get the added product in cart.

In my case i need to restrict the place order based on the product items in  cart.To achieve this i have created a custom Block and checking the items in cart.

Step 1 :Added My custom Block in sales_order_create_index.xml

```
     <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block class="[Package]\[Namespace]\Block\Adminhtml\Cart\CustomBlock"  template="Package_NameSpace::[template_Name]"/>
     </referenceContainer>
```

Step 2 : Created a Block name as "CustomBlock.php"

```
     namespace [Package]\[Namespace]\Block\Adminhtml\Cart;

     use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
     use Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create  as OrderCreate;

 class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
 {
       /** @var  OrderCreate */
       protected $_orderCreate;

       /**
        * CustomBlock constructor.
        * @param Context     $context
        * @param OrderCreate $orderCreate
        * @param array       $data
        */
       public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        OrderCreate $orderCreate,
        array $data = []
      )
     {
        $this->_orderCreate = $orderCreate;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
     }

   /**
    * Get Items Details 
    */
   public function getItemsDetails()
   {
      $quoteData =  $this->_orderCreate->getQuote();
      foreach ($quoteData->getAllItems() as $item) {
         echo "Product Sku".$item->getSku();
         // Insert Your code here 
      }

  }
}
```